# A Borel set problem

Tags: real-analysis

$E$ is a Borel subset $[0,1]$ such that $m(E)>0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, show for every $0<t<m(E)$, there is a Borel subset of $E'\subset E$ such that $m(E')=t$

My solution is as below

There is a $F_\sigma$ set $A$ such than $A\subset E$ and $m(A)=m(E)$, and $A=\cup I_i$, $I_i$ is interval and they are disjoint each other(because every closed set in $R$ is union of closed intervals and then decomposing these intervals into disjoint intervals), then change every interval $(a,b)$ to $(a,\frac{t}{m(E)}(b-a)+a)$, then we have done.

I think it is right, but it is tedious, so is there some easy way to solve it?

Remark:$[a,a]$ we also think it is an closed interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** The function $\phi: [0,1]\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto \int_0^x\chi_E dm = m(E\cap [0,x])$ is continuous.

**Step 2:** $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(1) = m(E)$.

**Step 3:** Intermediate value theorem.